Sencha EXTJS 7.7.0: how to add a scroll bar
I have tried using different components to add a scroll bar to my popup dialogue box:  overflowY: scroll( this does show the bar but still unable to scroll), scrollable: true and autoscroll:true (doesn’t show a scroll bar).
Is there a way I can add a scroll bar no matter what the resolution is ?
Expectation: able to scroll the window

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can use fiddle.sencha.com (need a forum.sencha.com login) to create an example. If you post your fiddle link here, we can help.

May be setting fixed height to dialog box like below could help here,
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        var dialog = Ext.create({
            xtype: 'dialog',
            title: 'Dialog',
            height:200,
            scrollable:true ,
            html: 'Content<br>goes<br>hereContent<br>goes<br>hereContent<br>goes<br>hereContent<br>goes<br>here',
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
});

